# Insertion sort for small subarrays in mergesort

Tags: mergesort

I am stuck while solving a problem in 'Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen', the problem is as follows,

Insertion sort in small arrays in merge sort

Although merge sort runs in O(n logn) worst-case time and insertion sort runs in O(n^2), the latter runs faster for small problem sizes. Consider a modification to Merge Sort in which n/k sublists of length k are sorted using insertion sort and then merged using standard merging mechanism.

To sort these n/k sublists of k length it takes O(nk) and to merge these n/k sub lists it takes  O(n lg(n/k))

So the modified algorithm takes O(nk) + O(n lg(n/k)) ,

what is  the largest asymptotic (Θnotation) value of k as a function of n for which the modified algorithm has the same asymptotic running time as standard merge sort?

How should k be chosen in practice?

These are the two things where I am stuck , any kind of help is appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The first question is asking, essentially, can k be greater than or equal to lg n and still have an asymptotic order of Θ(n lg n). If it's greater than, we know that the combination of the two sorting algorithms is not as efficient as just a merge sort. So we assume that k = Θ(lg n). If you plug in lg n where k is in your recurrence relation such that T(nlgn + n lg(n/lg(n)) and solve you will have your largest asymptotic value in Θnotation.

As for how K should be chosen, k should just be the maximum input size on which insertion sort is faster than merge. If we add some positive integers to both nk and nlgn, we know that k depends on the ratio between those two positive integers. Hope this helps!

ex xnk + ynlgn

x and y are the positive constants

so k = x/y because that minimizes the above expression. So k does not depend on n.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late but I think I can add some extra information regarding your second question. 
According to the Algorithms (4th edition) book written by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne

> Switching to insertion sort for small subarrays (length 15 or less, say) will improve the running > time of a typical mergesort implementation by 10 to 15 percent.